# Java: How can i solve the Error: "implicit super constructor is undefined"

Tags: java, class, inheritance, super, superclass

I have the following problem: `implicit super constructor is undefined must invoke another constructor java`.  I have two classes one which inherits and calls the super - Method.

**Person-Class:**

```
    public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String name;
        private Date birthday;
        private Gender gender = Gender.Unknown;

        Person(String fn, String n, Date d, Gender g){  
            firstName = fn;
            name = n;
            birthday = d;
            gender = g;
        }

        Person(Person p){
            firstName = p.firstName;
            name = p.name;
            birthday = new Date(p.birthday);
            gender = p.gender;
        }

        Person(String fn, String n){
            firstName = fn;
            name = n;
        }
```

And the second Class:

```
    public class Student extends Person implements Noten {
        private int nr;
        private String st;


        Student(int m, String s){
            this.nr= m;
            this.st= s;
        } 

        Student(Person p) {
            super(p);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
```

**Why upon extending** to class Person, Student class must implement Stundet(Person p) - Method?

One Solution: Add a Person() - Method to the `Person-Class`:

```
    Person(){
    System.out,println("Hello World"};
```

Still doesn't work.

**First Question:** Why does the super(p) - Method doesn't work?

**Second Question:** How do i make it work even without adding a `Person()` - with no Parameters to the `Person-Class`?

**Third Question:** Why didn't adding `Person()` - work?

Comment: It's looking for a Person() constructor. That is, one without parameters.

Comment: You need to create  No-argument constructor .   Person(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question:** Why does the super(p) - Method doesn't work?

It works fine, in that *second* `Student` constructor.

**Second Question:** How do i make it work even without adding a Person() - with no Parameters to the Person-Class?

You need to call *one* of the `Person` constructors using the `super(...)` syntax in that *first* `Student` constructor, because you *must* provide at least a `firstName` and a `name`.

**Third Question:** Why didn't adding Person() - work?

Added a no-argument constructor to `Person` does work, since the compiler can now implicitly call that `Person` constructor in the *first* `Student` constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is very good and detailed!!! Thank you!

Comment: In the Student(int m, String s){} Function should add an super() - Syntax?

Comment: @user13047397 Syntax is same as the other `super(...)` call, i.e. the keyword `super`, parenthesis, and the list of parameter values. It's like a method call to a method named `super`, and it will then choose the appropriate constructor depending on the number and type of parameter values, exactly like when you make normal method calls to an overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said, in order to construct an instance of your Student class, your class has to call **some** constructor in Person. Otherwise nothing in the parent class would be initialized, which would make extending Person useless.

Since in your first Student constructor you are not explicitly calling a person constructor, java tries to find a no-argument Person() constructor, which you don't have defined. Not finding it, you get this compilation error that you are seeing.

This is a very basic java question, so I'm assuming you are very new to java. I highly recommend reading a beginner's java book or online (in-depth) tutorial to get some of the basics down before you start coding or to refer to while you are practicing your coding. You will spend a lot of time spinning your wheels (or waiting for answers online) without those basics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought the child-class gets all the access to the variables and also methods of the Parent - Class, i didn't think that by initializing the Student() - Class it is necessary to use the super - Method at all. Optional Question: How should the initialization of the Student - Function look like?  Student(int m, String s, Person p){
this.nr= m; this.st= s; super(p)} ?